# google admob not clickable inside rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova, ads

I'm making one app in phone-gap so I've to deal in web-views only. In this app I need to put ads in the bottom of the screen. I'm using google admob for this. This generates floating ad window. I've put this window in bottom of the screen but problem is my webview content is hiding behind this window.

So, I've make one rectangle and add this google admob window in this rectangle. It solved my data hiding problem, but now it is not click able.

My code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{

    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    CGRect viewBounds = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].origin.x, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
    self.view.frame = viewBounds;


    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,theWebView.frame.size.height);

    bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin] autorelease];

    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"___ADMOBID___";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];


    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

How to make admob clickable inside rectangle (CGRect)???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually making the main view smaller, which basically - I guess - rescales its contents (including the webview Then you're placing the banner view right under the webview, but it'll show up anyways as you most probably have the `clipsToBounds` flag set to NO in your main view.

What you need to do is to make the webview (not the main view) smaller using `CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(kGADAdSizeBanner)` (and not the application frame) and then lay them both out accordingly.

Check the `self.view.clipsToBounds` flag and set it to YES whether in code or in IB in order to test correct behaviour, what you don't see in screen won't get any touches.